# Kentico ascx transformation syntax

Tags: c#, kentico

I've cobbled this together from various places. What i'm trying to do is show or hide a custom page type based on a user role, and a option from the admin side (visibiltyType).

So far it seems to be working, but i'm not sure of my conditional statement syntax is the best. C# is not my strong point.

Here's my transformation:

```html
<script runat="server">
  public bool visibility;
  public string visiblityType;
  protected override void OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
    {
      visiblityType = Eval("Visibility").ToString();
      if( CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.IsInRole("scona-cms_resources_branchdirectors", CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName) && visiblityType == "ncp" ){
        alert.Visible = true;  
      }
      if( CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.IsInRole("scona-cms_resources_salesreps", CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName) && visiblityType == "ncp" ){
        alert.Visible = true;  
      }
      if( CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.IsInRole("scona-kff-headoffice", CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName) && visiblityType == "ncp" ){
        alert.Visible = true;  
      }      
      if( CMS.Membership.MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser.IsInRole("scona-cms_resources_partnernetwork", CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName) && visiblityType == "cp" ){
        alert.Visible = true;  
      }      
      if (visiblityType == "both"){
        alert.Visible = true;
      }     
      
    }
</script>
<asp:placeholder id="alert" runat="server" Visible="false">  
  <li><%# Eval("Visibility") %> | <%# Eval("AlertDate") %> - <%# Eval("AlertTitle") %> <%# IfEmpty(Eval("AlertCopy"),"", " <a href='" +  GetDocumentUrl() + "'>Read More</a>")  %></li>
</asp:placeholder>
```

Comment: Can you try to override the OnLoad method instead of OnDataBinding?

Comment: That killed the page. Not sure of the error though.

Answer (score 1):

You may configure Page Type permissions and avoid all that checks in your transformation.

Comment: The first iteration of this used permissions. it worked, untill the need to came up to selectively show this to multiple groups. We noticed the editors only creating the item once, not as many were needed for the groups. 

i agree the condition statements are messy, but the AD roles here aren't clean.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on my end:

```
<script runat="server">
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
      alert.Visible = true;
    }
 </script>

<asp:placeholder id="alert" runat="server" visible="false">
  Placeholder
</asp:placeholder>
```

However in your case I would recommend to switch to **Text/XML** transformation because its **more efficient/faster** and it will be much easer for you to write such conditions. In your case it would be as nice as writing this:

```
{% if(CurrentUser.IsInRole("Editors")){ %}

User is in role editors

{% } else { %}

user is not in editors role

{% }%}
```

It can of course be more complex and you could even write a custom macro method for this purpose, but you get the idea :)

Comment: You may need to provide more proof Richard on the speed and efficiency because Kentico has specifically stated one is no faster than the other.  In fact, the standard ascx transformation could very well be considered faster because it doesn't have to be processed through the macro engine (which is C# code anyway).

One other thing is, if you check this transformation out, you can compile the ascx transformation and you cannot do so with a text transformation.  This comes in very handy for upgrades.